# Screenshot capture tool that supports Direct X

Tags: windows-7, screenshot

I'm searching for a Windows 7 all-in-one screen capture program (preferably freeware, or relatively cheap) that in addition to the regular desktop screen, supports in-game screenshots (such as the ones of Direct X)

[HyperSnap](http://www.hyperionics.com/hsdx/) can do this, but it's rather expensive. According to Google, many programs exist, but all of them seem to be shareware, and/or ridiculously expensive to boot.

Comment: Is this the same hypersnap you are looking at? http://www.hyperionics.com/hsdx/   I found **hypersnap 8** for $40 what is your budget?  FRAPS is $37.

Comment: I'm mostly trying to find a freeware utility.

Comment: Oddly desktop screenshooting can be harder than DirectX.  If you load **Steam** it has free screen capturing.  The AMD gaming client **Raptr** has same stuff built-in free.  NVIDIA has an equivalent, but I forgot the name.  However, I don't know if any of them do standard desktop screen captures.

Answer (score 1):

MSI afterburner (I have not used it, but friends recommend it) free of course

both screen and video capture works with a variety of video cards, not just MSI (your mileage may vary)

video capture and screen capture have their own tabs.

http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm
http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/predator.htm

http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/version_history.htm

- JPEG screenshot quality settings are no longer power user oriented and can be adjusted directly from the client application GUI
- Screen capture implementation is now multithreaded to minimize the impact on the game performance when saving screenshots on the systems with multicore CPUs

article on ghacks.net about MSI afterburner (good read)

http://www.ghacks.net/2011/07/25/capture-video-with-msi-afterburner/

Basic Guide to Recording w/ MSI Afterburner (Video + PDF) tutorial on video capture
http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=373159

if you will do video capture, **kindly research your choice of video codecs** (for best performance) and please **do not download those all-in-one video codec packs** they might break the current video codecs you have. Download and test video codecs one by one and download only from trusted sites of course.

Answer (score 0):

[Virtual Dub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) is freeware and can record your entire gameplay. You could select your screenshots at a later stage then. I know this is not exactly what you've asked for, but it's a good and free workaround.